# How to make a HTTP Basic Authentication post request where password is generated by TOTP in Python?

Tags: python, http, authentication, post

The task is to make a HTTP post request to *url* sending a json string *data* over, *url* is protected by HTTP Basic Authentication, I need to provide an **Authorization:** field in header, and *emailAdd* is the **userid** of Basic Authentication, **password** is generated by TOTP, where digits is 10-digit, time step is 30s, T0 is 0, hash function uses sha512, and shared secret is *emailAdd + "ABCD"*.

My code is like:

```
import requests, base64, json
from passlib.totp import TOTP
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth


totp = TOTP(key = base64.b32encode(shared_secret.encode()), digits = 10, alg = "sha512")
password = totp.generate().token

r = requests.Session()
#auth = base64.b64encode((''.join(userid) + ':' + ''.join(password)).encode())
r.headers.update({"Content-Type": "application/json"})      #this is task required
#r.headers.update({"Authorization": "Basic " + auth.decode()})

res = r.post(url, json = data, auth = (userid, password))
print(res.status_code)
print(res.content)
```

But I failed authentication, I think the password should be correct, and there is something wrong with post request, can anyone please tell me what the problem is? Also, I'm in a different time zone from the server, does it make any difference on TOTP generated password? And I'm running python on windows, if that matters.

Thanks

Comment: To use `HTTPBasicAuth` in `requests`, you can simply use `r.post(url, data, auth=(username, password))`. Further, to pass json data, you can use `r.post(url, json=an_object_like_dict_or_list, auth=(username, password))`. You needn't to manually modify headers.

Comment: @Srwa thanks for that, I've modified the code, but that is not the cause of authentication failure, any ideas?